# SQL Update column with random data from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to insert random names of table 2 into the records of table 1.

- Table 1: ID  ... Name  ... FurtherData
- Table 2: Name

Is it possible to achieve this in a simple SQL statement?

Kind regards

Comment: is there any relationship b/w two tables?

Comment: Are you inserting new records or updating existing records?

Comment: No, the tables have no relationship. Table 1 has more than 100 000 records and table 2 contains for 30 000 name. Each record of table 1 should  have a random name of table 2. So, many names may appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to insert all names from table2 into table1 those are not already there

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name)
SELECT table2.Name 
From table2 
Where table2.Name NOT IN (SELECT table1.Name From table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to get 100 random names:

```
insert into table1(name)
    select name
    from (select name
          from table2
          order by dbms_random.random()
         ) t
    where rownum <= 100;
```

Of course, you may want to supply values for the other columns, but your question seems to be specifically about getting random values from the second table.

In Oracle 12, you don't need the subquery.  You can use `fetch first <n> rows only`.